# Jasmine async test error handling

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this test in Karma/Jasmine:

```
    it('async error test', done => {

        function foo(){
            throw new Error('test error');
        }

        function async(){
            setTimeout(() => {
                try{
                    let res = foo();
                    expect(res).toBe(5);
                } catch(e){
                    console.log('in error');
                    done(e);
                }
            });
        }

        async();
    });
```

The `done(e)` supposed to fail the test but somehow it shows me that the test has been succeeded.

In Mocha/Chai stack it works as expected and the test is failed, do anyone know how should I handle async errors with Karma/Jasmine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jasmine and mocha/chai APIs are slightly different in this situation. In jasmine, the `done` function does not take any arguments. So, if an error is passed in, it is just ignored.

In mocha/chai, an error passed in to the done function will fail the test.

If you are using jasmine, instead of passing in the error, you will need to do something like this in the catch block:

```
} catch(e) {
  expect(true).toBe(false);
  done();
}
```

As you have written this for jasmine, the test is passing as it should. Your `foo()` function throws an error, it is caught, and the test ends. Simple as that. `expect(res).toBe(5)` is never reached. And the test ends normally without any errors.

Comment: thanks, i think really bad practice, because even with that, it'll be hard to see the error itself during writing the test itself. 

Maybe this is one of the motivations to use more well-organized (and well documented) runner like `mocha` that support also `async` / `await`..